# Populating excel using PHPExcel extension from Yii

Tags: php, excel, yii

This my code:

```
    $col =  array("Year", "Month");
    $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from mytable WHERE `column` = '".$cnp."' ")->queryAll();

   $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result, array());

   $excelGenerator = new ExcelView(array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => array(  
            array(
                'header' => 'Year',
                'value' => '$data->year',
            ),
            array(
                'header' => 'Month',
                'value' => '$data->month',
            ),
        ),
            ));
   $excelGenerator->run();
```

The result of this is an excel file with two column name Year and Month, but How can I populate with data taken from my select ? This select returns multiple results. thx

Comment: Link to the extension please?

Comment: yeah, sure: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [`CArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider), `value` should be accessed as an array:

```
'value' => '$data["month"]',
```

You can also use the [CGridView shorthand columns structure](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail)

```
'columns' => array(
    'year',
    'month::Month of Year',
    'other_column:type:Other Column',
```